# What are the Eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: determinant

I Need to compute the Eigenvalues of the following General Matrix. Let $b\geqslant a$. Consider the $(a+b+1)\times (a+b+1)$-Matrix $C$ with the following entries.
$$
c_{1,1}=c_{a+b+1,0}=1
$$
and
$$
c_{i,j}=1~\text{ for }1\leqslant i\leqslant a+b, j=i+1
$$
and all other entries are $0$.

*Example*: a=2, b=3

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Sorry that I asked the question so confusing before. Note, that I Need the Eigenvalues, not the determinant as I asked before, sorry.

Comment: Your notation is not clear. Do you mean $a_{0,0}=a_{a+b,0}=1$? Also, standard notation begins at $a_{1,1}$, not $a_{0,0}$.

Comment: Yes, i mean $a_{0,0}=a_{a+b,0}=1$. Sorry, I started with $a_{0,0}$ not with $a_{1,1}$.

Comment: No, there is a 1 in the left low Corner... I'll edit my post to make it more clear-

Comment: Perhaps you should make your question more clear, and include an explicit example: say for $a=2,\ b=3$.

Comment: @mathfemi Do you want to get $\left\lvert 
\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1&1&0&\cdots&0\\
1&1&1&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&1&\ddots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&1\\
1&1&1&\cdots&1

\end{array}
\right\rvert$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eigenvalues you need to calculate $|A-\lambda I|$. So you get
$$
|A-\lambda I|=\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda&1&0&\dots&0\\0&-\lambda&1&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&1\\
1&0&0&\dots&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} =
$$

$ = (1-\lambda)*(-\lambda)^{a+b} +(-1)^{a+b} = (-1)^{a+b}*((1-\lambda)\lambda^{a+b}+1) = 0$

so the eigenvalues are the solutions of
$(1-\lambda)\lambda^{a+b}+1 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

If I've well understood, the matrix is as follows:
$$A-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda&1&0&0&\dots &0\\
0&-\lambda&1&0&\dots&0\\0&0&-\lambda&1&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&0&\dots&1\\
1&0&0&0&\dots&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$$
You just have to develop the determinant along the first column:
\begin{align*}
\det(A-\lambda I)&=(1-\lambda)\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&1&0&\dots&0\\0&-\lambda&1&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&1\\
0&0&0&\dots&-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}+(-1)^{a+b}\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\dots &0\\
-\lambda&1&0&\dots&0\\0&-\lambda&1&\dots&0\\\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&1
\end{bmatrix}\\[1.5ex]&=(-1)^{a+b}\bigl((1-\lambda)\lambda^n+1\bigr)=(-1)^{a+b+1}\bigl(\lambda^{n+1}-\lambda^n-1\bigr).\end{align*}